# How to remove/hide Yoast's "SEO" tab in admin panel?

Tags: plugins, admin, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I don't want this shown to members who register for my website as it's confusing and irrelevant for them.

I assume some code added to `functions.php` will do the trick but what code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This *should* hide it for everyone but the admin. If you run into any issues, you can use a plugin like [Advanced Access Manager](http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-access-manager/) to get the job done. With that you will have more control of what each user level has access to.

```
function hide_yoastseo() {
if ( !current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) :
    remove_action('admin_bar_menu', 'wpseo_admin_bar_menu',95);
    remove_menu_page('wpseo_dashboard');
endif;
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'hide_yoastseo');
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Yoast SEO but this is what I use for non admin users:

```
function my_remove_menu_items() {
if ( !current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) : // IF NON ADMIN USER
    //remove_menu_page( 'index.php' ); // DASHBOARD
    //remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=custom_post_type' ); // CPT
    //remove_submenu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=custom_post_type', 'post-new.php?post_type=custom_post_type' ); // CPT SUB MENU
    //remove_menu_page( 'edit.php' ); // POSTS
    //remove_menu_page( 'upload.php' ); // MEDIA
    //remove_menu_page( 'edit-comments.php' ); // COMMENTS
    //remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=page' ); // PAGES
    //remove_menu_page( 'plugins.php' ); // PLUGINS
    //remove_menu_page( 'themes.php' ); // APPEARANCE
    //remove_menu_page( 'users.php' ); // USERS
    //remove_menu_page( 'tools.php' ); // TOOLS
    //remove_menu_page( 'options-general.php' ); // SETTINGS
endif;
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_remove_menu_items' );
```

Obviously, this goes in your functions.php and you uncomment what you want to hide.

Hope this is a good starting point, Ian.

Answer (score 0):

I used:

```
function hide_yoastseo() {
if ( !current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) :
    remove_action('admin_bar_menu', 'wpseo_admin_bar_menu',95);
    remove_menu_page('wpseo_dashboard');
endif;
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'hide_yoastseo');
```

... but then the **media library in grid view** did not load and I could not add a featured image. Then I changed **'admin_init'** to **'admin_menu'** and it resolved the media library grid view problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your SEO page menu is redirecting to 'admin.php?page=wpseo_workouts'

The below code worked for me. here I am hiding the SEO menu for our custom user(non-admin). you can remove if condition.

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_remove_menu_pages' );
function my_remove_menu_pages() {
  global $user_ID;
  if ( $user_ID == 13 ) { //your user id
    remove_menu_page('wpseo_workouts');
  }
}
```